# Install Google tracking, apache level

Tags: apache-2.2, google-analytics

I find it annoying to paste in the Google code for the tracker at the end of each page.

Is there a way to have Apache deliver the <script> with each *.htm and *.php file downloaded?

Answer (score 4):

If you use Google PageSpeed Module you could set 
in the .htaccess:

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_ga
ModPagespeedAnalyticsID <Analytics ID>
```

[See details here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-insert-ga).

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible via Apache. You can use the add-handler to add an action for all .htm or .php file on a per server, per directory or even in .htaccess.

```
Action add-footer /path/to/footer.cgi
AddHandler add-footer .htm
```

Where footer.cgi is a script which will add the footer to the file.

You can also do this within the php processing (although it would then only work for php files) using

```
php_value auto_append_file /path/to/footer.php
```

This will add the code in footer.php to your PHP code.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter where the GA code is executed; browsers will execute JavaScript placed after `</html>`, even.

Comment: Ah ha, I didn't try it, but sounds right.

Comment: @yc01 of course dropping a script block outside the main html block wouldn't be what you'd call valid (x)HTML.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem a year ago by writing a module.  It looks like someone else did this as well: https://github.com/dragon3/mod_google_analytics.

This is especially useful if you are front-ending an application you can't modify or something in tomcat you don't want to tweak.

After looking at that module, it seems like they don't check for text/html.. which might mean the module could trash your binary content if you don't use AddOutputFilterByType ..  text/html.  Be warned!